# Import python module in package adjacent to sibling directory of program

Tags: python

Given the following python project structure:

- example_dir

  - alpha.py
  - beta.py
  - chi/__init__.py
  - chi/delta.py
  - epsilon/__init__.py
  - epsilon/fudge.py

Where *alpha.py* contains:

```
from beta import beta_var
print(beta_var)

from chi.delta import delta_var
print(delta_var)

from epsilon.fudge import fudge_var
print(fudge_var)
```

*beta.py* contains:

```
from chi.delta import delta_func

beta_var = delta_func()
```

*chi.py* contains:

```
delta_var = 42

def delta_func():
    return 69
```

And *fudge.py* contains:

```
from chi.delta import delta_func

fudge_var = delta_func()
```

I can run *alpha.py* directly as expected.

I can run *beta.py* too.

But when I run *fudge.py*, whether via `python epsilon/fudge.py` or `cd epsilon && python fudge.py`, Python displays the error:

*ImportError: No module named chi.delta*

How can I run *fudge.py* directly, and successfully access `delta_func` defined in *delta.py*, while still being able to run *alpha.py*? Ideally, I'd like to invoke `python fudge.py` from within the *epsilon* subdirectory.

I thought I understood the fundamentals of Python modules and packages, but perhaps I do not, as this seems to be far more difficult than it needs to be!

Comment: are  you able to do: `from ..chi.delta import delta_func` ?

Comment: Ahh, I see. You don't have a `__init__.py` within the `example_dir` folder. Create that and it should work

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri After creating _example_dir/\_\_init\_\_.py_ and using `..chi.delta` neither _alpha.py_ nor _fudge.py_ work. Running _alpha.py_ raises a _ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package_. Running _epsilon/fudge.py_ raises a _ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run it directly like this:

```
python -m epsilon.fudge
```

...provided your current working directory is `example_dir`. (Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to run the script inside of the `epsilon` directory.)

---

**Simple Explanation:** In short, this will force Python to run your script as part of a package.

This allows you to do:

```
from chi.delta import delta_func
```

in your `fudge.py`, even though `delta.py` is in the separate `chi` directory. It works because (in this case) doing `python -m` runs your script as a part of a package, which contains all of the directories in `example_dir`.